# A representation of Dirac-$\delta$

Tags: limits, dirac-delta

Prove that
$$g_\epsilon (x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac1 \epsilon \frac1 \pi e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2}$$
is a Dirac-$\delta$ function.

---

This is a homework question I'm stuck with. I'm probably missing a very simple point, and can't seem to figure it out. Any help to prompt me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

What I've done so far is the following.

I need to show that,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g_\epsilon (x)dt=f(0)$$
So let $t=\epsilon x$,
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \frac1 \epsilon e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2}dt=$$
$$\stackrel{t=\epsilon x}{=}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\epsilon x) \frac1 \epsilon \frac1 \pi e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2}\epsilon dx$$
$$=f(0) \frac1 \pi \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2} dx$$
And since $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2}=0$, the result is $0$, not $f(0)$.

Another approach was to just set $t=x$ so that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1 \epsilon e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2}=\sqrt\pi$ would cancel out with $1/\pi$, but then I'm left with $f(x)$ instead of $f(0)$.

Comment: In your first line, you have $f(t) g_{\epsilon} (x)dt$, but you haven't defined $x$ yet. That $x$ should be a $t$, and then your change of variables will do what you want it to do.

Comment: That's it. Indeed I have missed a _very_ simple point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jordan pointed out in a comment, if we demand $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) g_{\epsilon} (t) dt = f(0)$ and let $t=\epsilon x$ then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) g_{\epsilon} (t) dt = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \frac{1}{\epsilon\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-t^2/\epsilon^2}dt =\\ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\epsilon x) \frac{1}{\epsilon\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2} \epsilon dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(0) \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2} dx =\\ f(0) \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cdot \sqrt{\pi} = f(0) $$

P.S. I think you need $\sqrt{\pi}$ when defining $g_\epsilon$.