# Limit of an integral of a continuous function multiplied with the mollifier

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\omega(x)\in L^1\left(R^n\right)\cap L^2(R^n)\cap C(R^n)$, $\epsilon>0$. How to  prove 
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{(2\epsilon)^{n/2}}\int_{R^n}\omega(x)e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4\epsilon}}dx=(2\pi)^{n/2}\omega(0)?$$

Given that for $\epsilon>0$,
$$\frac{1}{(4\pi\epsilon)^{n/2}}\int_{R^n}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4\epsilon}}dx=1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity may be used to define the essential property of, and the very same, Dirac delta function in $\mathbb R^n$

Following [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1025090/362604), we can adapt the result for $\mathbb R^n$

First,

$$\frac{1}{(4\pi\epsilon)^{n/2}}\int_{R^n}\exp\left(-\frac{\vert x\vert^2}{4\epsilon}\right)dx=1\implies$$

$$\implies\int_{R^n}\frac{1}{(2\epsilon)^{n/2}}\exp\left(\frac{\vert x\vert^2}{4\epsilon}\right)dx=(2\pi)^{n/2}$$

As the identity holds for $\epsilon>0$, with $\epsilon=1$ we have,

$$\int_{R^n}\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\exp\left(\frac{\vert x\vert^2}{4}\right)dx=(2\pi)^{n/2}$$
Now, let be $x=\sqrt{\epsilon}t$, then $dx=\epsilon^{n/2}dt$

$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{R^n}\omega(x)\frac{1}{(2\epsilon)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\vert x\vert^2}{4\epsilon}\right)dx=$$

$$=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{R^n}\omega(\epsilon t)\frac{1}{(2\epsilon)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\vert\sqrt{\epsilon}t\vert^2}{4\epsilon}\right)\epsilon^{n/2}dt=$$

$$=\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_{R^n}\omega(\epsilon t)\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\vert t\vert^2}{4}\right)dt=\int_{R^n}\omega(0)\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\vert t\vert^2}{4}\right)dt=$$

$$=(2\pi)^{n/2}\omega(0)$$

Comment: In the last step, why can we take the limit into the integral?

Comment: Yes. The integrand converges to an integrable function ($\omega(0)$ times the mollifier) and both, $\omega$ and the mollifier, are $L^2$, so its product is too. By the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) we can take the limit into the integral

Comment: which function is the dominant function for $\omega(0)$ times the mollifier?

Comment: You only need [the functions to be bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem) and, by hypothesis, they all are (your very first line) and its integrals and the integral of the limiting function to exist.

Comment: You mean since $\omega(\epsilon t)\rightarrow \omega(0)$, so it is bounded. Then, $|\omega(\epsilon t)|\leq M$ for some $M>0$. And then, $\omega(\epsilon t)\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}exp\left(-|t|^2/4\right)<=M exp\left(-|t|^2/4\right)$, which is $L^1$, then we use the dominant convergent theorem. Is it right?

Comment: The first line of your post is defining the function $\omega$ as belonging to a class of functions, the properties of wich are summarized and asumed. $L^1$ and $L^2$.

Comment: No, you have it better. $\omega$ and the mollifier are $L^1$, then $\omega(\epsilon t)\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}exp\left(-|t|^2/4\right)<M$ by the structure of $L^1$ You only need for the integrand to be bounded.

Comment: But if we bound the whole integrant by a constant $M$, the integral will be infinite.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I think you don't need to find the dominating function, it obviously exist. If you insist, you can get the one you constructed, yes.

Comment: What's the context of your question, where does it come from?

Comment: It's from Evans PDE. In page 184, it's one of the step in the proof of the Plancherel's theorem.

Comment: You have your proof, even with an explicit form for the dominating function :) I liked this problem because it's related, as I said, to the Dirac delta function. In fact, it proves the adequacy of the main property, so is $\int f(x)\delta(x) dx=f(0)$